# In django how to delete the images which are not in databases?

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a blog website in Django. I have posted multiple articles on the website. After deleting the article, the article gets deleted but the media files are not removed. I want to delete all media files which are not referred to the articles.

I know, I can create Django post-delete signal and delete media files from there. But it will applicable for only future use. I want to delete previous media files which are not in my database.

Answer (score 1):

first install this:

```
pip install django-cleanup
```

then, add this in settings file inside your installed_apps:

```
'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig'
```

It will delete your media files.

Comment: `django-cleanup` package works only for existing models. I want to delete the media files which are stored by deleted models.

Answer (score -1):

Just use this program to delete your unused media files.

This command deletes all media files from the MEDIA_ROOT directory which are no longer referenced by any of the models from installed_apps.

```
import os
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from django.conf import settings
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        physical_files = set()
        db_files = set()


    media_root = getattr(settings, 'MEDIA_ROOT', None)
      if media_root is not None:
        for relative_root, dirs, files in os.walk(media_root):
            for file_ in files:
                relative_file = os.path.join(os.path.relpath(relative_root, 
                media_root), file_)
                physical_files.add(relative_file)

     deletables = physical_files - db_files
     if deletables:
        for file_ in deletables:
            os.remove(os.path.join(media_root, file_))
```

Comment: Correct if I am wrong, but the code in this answer will delete ALL files since the variable `db_files` is defined as an empty `set` and never redefined to be the list of database instances referencing the files (the indentation in the code example seems wrong too)